# count different values of a single column in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am working on Laravel framework. I have a table named 'traffic', contains data for visited users of my website, as like below:

```
id browser
1  Firefox
2  Firefox
3  Chrome
4  IE
5  Chrome
```

Now, I want to get the total number of each browser used in a single query. Here is my current query:

```
Traffic::selectRaw("count(case when browser = 'IE' then 1 end) as IE")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when browser = 'Firefox' then 1 end) as Firefox")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when browser = 'Chrome' then 1 end) as Chrome")
    ->groupBy('browser')
    ->first();
```

Which outputs similar to:

```
Row 1: IE=0, Firefox=0, Chrome=2
Row 2: IE=0, Firefox=2, Chrome=0
Row 3: IE=1, Firefox=0, Chrome=0
```

But, I want the result to be similar to:

```
Row 1: IE=1, Firefox=2, Chrome=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` logic to get a table-level summary:

```
Traffic::selectRaw("COUNT(CASE WHEN browser = 'IE' THEN 1 END) AS IE")
    ->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE WHEN browser = 'Firefox' THEN 1 END) AS Firefox")
    ->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE WHEN browser = 'Chrome' THEN 1 END) AS Chrome")
    ->get();
```

Comment: You should not be seeing this error, as the underlying raw query should in fact be valid.